# How to include a link of one file in an other file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am extracting some information from one file say `f1.txt` and writing that information to another file `f2.txt`.

In `f2.txt` I want to keep a link such that, when I click that link `f1.txt` should open.

How it can be done in `python` ?

Comment: What are you viewing the txt file with? Usually it's nonsensical to talk about a link in a _txt_ file.

Comment: @gnibbler ok let me elaborate it some more. i have a file(not necessarily txt file) by using phython im taking the information from that file and appendeing the same to other file. at the end of the line in second file ,i want to give the location of the file from where i copied that information. and a hyperlink. when i click that hyperlink , the original file should open.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with a file like `f2.txt`. If it was `f2.html`, you'd do something like this:

```
<a href="file:///c:/path/to/f1.txt">information from f1.txt</a>
```

If the files are in the same directory, you can use just the file name:

```
<a href="f1.txt">information from f1.txt</a>
```

If you want to point to a specific *place* inside `f1.txt`, you've got to create a HTMLized version of it, containing code like this:

```
<a name="L1">[line 1 from f1.txt]</a><br>
<a name="L2">[line 2 from f1.txt]</a><br>
...
```

Then, link to the specific line by appending `#LX` to the `href` address, where `X` is the line number, like this:

```
<a href="f1.html#L34">information from f1.txt</a>
```

Python is not a text file viewer, so I don't see what it has to do with this, except generating `f2.txt`.

Inbar has explained how to actually write the file, so if you just combine the two answers, you're all set. But you must make `f2` an html file, there's no such things as hyperlinks in text files.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
def func1(src, dst):
    """copies contents of src to dst with a 'link'"""

    with open(src, 'r') as file_src:
        with open(dst, 'w') as file_dst:
            file_dst.writeline(src) #or however you want to represent "link"
            file_dst.write(file_src.read())
```